# Email as Username in an existing django app

Tags: python, django

I created an app where I used to require an `email` and a `username` for signup.

Now I would like to change this so that any existing users have their username changed to their email. Any new users will not see the username field upon signup, but in the backend they'd be the same.

I was thinking that I could just set the `max_length` to the length of email? Then in the backend, I could just set the username to the email when the user signs up. What am I missing here?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: The question is simple: How do I achieve using the email as a username in an existing Django app.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to change the authentication backend and then change your models. More information can be found on the django documentation website:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/